# How to add title and script on vue template with nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i want to add `title`, `description` and other html `meta` for SEO.

how i can do it in vue template?

for example i want to add the `meta` on my `template.vue`.

for some reason i have to add script too on that template.

my code is like this:

```
head: {
  title: 'my title',
  script: [
     { src: '/js/theme.js', defer: true }
  ]
},
```

code above is error.

if i use return like this:

```
head () {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'My custom description' }
      ],
      script: [
         { src: '/js/theme.js', defer: true }
      ]
    }
}
```

`meta` will work, but the script will not showing.

like i say, i can't put the script on `nuxt-config.js` don't know why, but the page will error.

Answer (score 0):

[image]check this image hope it will help your problem